# Space Designer presets in Pro Tools

Tags: reverb, convolution, pro-tools, export

Hi all,

I've just got a quick question. I've been working on a project in Pro Tools that requires a constant battlefield soundscape a couple of miles off in the distance. I've spent countless days tweaking a number of convolution reverbs trying to get the perfect ER and diffuse field sounds.

However, just today, I have managed to use the EQ envelope within Space Designer to create (imo) a realistic model for the way the attack and decay of gunfire appears and disintegrates.
My problem is, the preset I have created is housed within Logic's Space Designer and I need to be able to use it in Pro Tools as that's my main DAW.

I didn't know whether there was A) a way of exporting this preset into a PT-compatible format (Altiverb, AIR, IR-1) or B) an RTAS convolution plug-in that allows me to create volume AS WELL AS EQ envelopes for IR files so that I may at least be able to replicate my existing preset.

Can anyone give me any sort of idea at all?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @LampEight - How did you solve it?

Comment: Sorry I hadn't updated you all with the situation. I ended up just fine tuning using Altiverb in the end as, looking back, I wasn't even that happy with the Space Designer version. I recommend the answer that @David gave in having a larger set of original assets at your disposal... especially when it comes to gunfire. I'll make note of that for the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend starting from distant assets.  Most up to date weapons libs include some distanced material.  The stereo fields tend to be richer, and the frequency rolloffs and dynamics much more naturalistic.  just my 2 cents coming from a video game designer who has put distant weaponry in tons of projects.

Comment: @David Rovin - I agree with you - what we do is have the tail from the gun recording then sweeten it with a bit of 'artificial reverb' either realtime in the game engine or pre-rendered. the tails of different guns sound very different and unique. something that would be very time consuming and complex to try to recreate artificially.

Answer (score 2):

What if you send a sweep through your preset in Logic'Space Designer. Record/bounce it and import it in another IR plugin. :)

I don't now space designer:
So, do you mean by "eq envelope" that different bands have different attack, sustain and decay values, or does the eq react to the input like an envelope filter?

I guess in the second case it would not be representable in the IR-sweep.

Comment: "What if you send a sweep through your preset in Logic'Space Designer. Record/bounce it and import it in another IR plugin"

Good call.. Have you tried this before? Would be interested to know if that works?

Comment: Should work. There are IR samples from Lexicon reverbs. I think they get them like this. I haven't tried it but I will do so later. 

Comment: So the emulation of the reverbs funcioned very well. I emulated a preset from Waves TrueVerb and one from Waves IR-L with a 30 second sweep. You can even choose a longer one to increase quality.
Now I would like to know if it works with LampEigth's envelope eq but I don't have access to Space Designer. 

Answer (score 1):

In theory... I say so because I haven't tried myself but have read that this is possible on other forums.

you can use Jack OSX to link Protools and Logic. So what you would want to do is to use route an output from Protools into Logic, and then an output from Logic back to Protools. If you're only using the Sound Designer plugin, I guess you would only have to keep Logic open and just treat this connection like an effect sends bus. From memory, Jack only started working with Protools 9.

this will give you some ideas

http://blog.dubspot.com/traktor-to-ableton-live-how-to-route-audio/

http://www.gearslutz.com/board/music-computers/485645-logic-pro-9-1-mainstage-2-instruments-pro-tools.html

Another option is Soundflower

http://duc.avid.com/showthread.php?t=286398

I don't have the solution for you, but hopefully this information gears you to someone who will.

Answer (score 0):

You should a take look at Reverberate from [LiquidSonics](http://liquidsonics.com)

The built-in presets and IRs are questionable, but I've found it rather indispensable for mangling my own impulses.